# Problem with function call inside preg_replace

Tags: php, variables, preg-replace

Does not work, the $1-value is lost when calling the function:

```
echo preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">'.findTopDomain('$1').'</a>', $text);
```

Works fine, outputs: stackoverflow.com

```
echo preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">'.findTopDomain('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask').'</a>' , $text);
```

I need to send the $1 value to a function from within preg_replace.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [*e* modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to have the substitution expression to be executed:

```
preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"e', '"<a href=\\"$1\\">".findTopDomain("$1")."</a>"', $text)
```

Note that your substitution now has to be a valid PHP expression. In this case the expression would be evaluated to:

```
"<a href=\"$1\">".findTopDomain("$1")."</a>"
```

And don’t forget to escape the output with at least `htmlspecialchars`:

```
preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"e', '"<a href=\\"".htmlspecialchars("$1")."\\">".htmlspecialchars(findTopDomain("$1"))."</a>"', $text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`php_replace_callback()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)?

> Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback